# how to send notification through tivoili identity manager 5.1

Tags: tivoli-identity-manager

I want to setup an alert when ever there is a password change in TIM, a specific person should receive the notification informing him about the change.

Comment: I am self learning this tool... so not quite know from where to configure sending an email  for any a/c change activity.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize the ISIM/ITIM Account -> Change Password operations wherein you need to customize the exiting workflow by adding the Mail/Work order node at the end of ChangePassword extension.

In the mail/Work Order node add the participant you want such that a notification is sent to the same in case of change password operation.